# Protect a double var without using mutex

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, mutex

Greeting !!

I've a c ap running in linux which is a POSIX multithreading application ,
In thread 1 , I set global var in this way :

```
Pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex1); 
for(idx=0;idx<1000;idx++)
{
      Data1[idx].doubleval = idx * 100.0 * anothervar  ;
}//for 
Pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex1);
```

in thread2 , I get global var it in this way :

```
Pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex1); 
for(idx=0;idx<1000;idx++)
{
     doublexxx = Data1[idx].doubleval ;
     DoSomething(doublexxx) ;
}//for 
Pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex1);
```

Now , suppose I don't want to use Mutex in my ap , if thread1 is setting Data1[33].doubleval while thread2 is reading Data1[33].doubleval , will Data1[33].doubleval be a very strange value ?   I mean , for example , double var has 4 bytes , while thread1 is setting Data1[33].doubleval first 2 bytes , not finish later 2 bytes , at this monent 
thread2 is trying to read Data1[33].doubleval ....is it possible ?

If it is possible , how can I do to protect a double var without this kind of problem ?
Mutex is great to use , I just wonder if there is another way to protect a double var 
which thread1 is writing in it , at least thread2 try to read from the same var 
will wait that 4 bytes double var finished !!!

Comment: Just use the mutex and you don't have to worry about it. Why go out of your way to needlessly create a problem?

Comment: Seriously; if you don't want to lock, then you shouldn't be using threads.

Comment: Thanks ,My application use too many threads , and I'd like to ap run as fast as possible ,I have no idea how mutex_lock effect performance , actually all mutex used in a small memory strcpy block, but still I am told to make it run faster ....thanks for all kindly reply !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not it's possible to read a "partially written" value depends on a large number of factors (e.g. target system and alignment) and is definitely not portable. For an example, imagine this code running on a 16-bit CPU with floating point support emulated in software.

Even with a mutex, the second thread's behaviour will still be undefined because it won't know if it has read data before the first thread wrote it or after the first thread wrote it.

I suspect that there's higher level problems with your design - perhaps you should be using a condition variable to make the second thread wait until the first thread has written.

I also suspect that the reason you're asking about removing the mutex is to improve scalability/performance. For example, so that one thread to use one part of the array while a different thread modifies a completely different part of the same array. If this is the reason behind your question, then the solution depends on your scenario - it could be as simple as using multiple locks (one mutex per area of the array, up to one mutex per entry), but might mean implementing a "reader/writer" lock (so that multiple threads are allowed to read from the array at the same time, as long as no other thread is writing).

Comment: Thanks...Thread1 writing data in endless loop , also Thread2 reading data in endless loop , My goal is to get more performance, all I care is that thread2 won't get strange value , if that value is correct value no matter thread1 write it fast or slow , and then I won't use mutex...because thread2 just need a reasonable value asap, The most I scare is that thread2 read a unreasonable value, like I said 2 bytes are written in thread1 , not finish in later 2 bytes something like that ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem to be worried about is not the value getting read halfway through a write; I don't know of a system where this is possible.  The issue is that your second thread's behavior will be undefined, because you don't know whether it will read before or after the first thread writes to a given section of memory.  Without a mutex, or something functionally equivalent, there's no way to get well-defined behavior.

Comment: Word tearing can definitely happen on Alpha processors. On x86 CPUs, I believe it can only happen for unaligned accesses, assuming the compiler doesn't do anything funny. (GCC, for example, sometimes writes a value back to memory after reading it, even if the code doesn't change the value. That can cause a write by another thread to be lost.)

Comment: Suppose thread2 always read a global double var g1 which thread1 always write , these 2 threads are both in endless loop ,if g1 now is 1.55, and thread1 is going to execute g1=1.66 , if thread2 is going  to read g1 at the same monent without mutex  , if i can make sure g1 must =1.55 or 1.66 , no else value possible , then I think I will avoid mutex !!